# How to store webpage content into SQL Server?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xhtml

I have a page called www dot abc dot com and there is some content in that page; now I want to store this content in SQL Server.

I heard that it can be achieved using DOM. If not in DOM please suggest me the possible ways. I searched in this forum for similar but I couldn't find.

Comment: which server side script are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Possible repeat question.

Take a look at the following...

- [How do you store HTML documents in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456771/how-do-you-store-html-documents-in-a-database)
- [How to store web page content in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220914/how-to-store-web-page-content-in-sql-server)

And there are probably many more if you do a quick search...

You may also like to read the FAQ for future reference https://stackoverflow.com/faq